# How might humidity inhibit the drying or hardening chemical oxidation process of linseed-based oil paint?

Tags: organic-oxidation, evaporation, humidity, drying

I understand that linseed-based oil paint essentially dries or hardens by the chemical process of oxidation and not by evaporation. If it is possible that humidity somehow inhibits the chemical drying process in a related physical way, how might that occur?

Comment: Has anybody ever shown that humidity inhibits the chemical oxidation of linseed-based oil paint ? Never heard about this process.

Comment: I’m guessing conservation studies tend to examine humidity's effect on linseed oil painting after being painted. I believe actual curing takes months. I have seen one or two artists’ websites which suggest humidity may slow drying, for example.
- see "The temperature of your room" subheading under https://finearttutorials.com/guide/how-long-does-oil-paint-take-to-dry/#How_does_oil_paint_dry.
The conclusion of the conservation article below notes humidity can inhibit cross-linking, but I'm not sure about how humidity would slow drying. 
https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6445089/